# I think not vs. I think no

Tags: negation

If I want to answer negatively this question,

Is science any thing other than logic applied to the manifested existences?

Should I say *I think not* or *I think no*?

Comment: I would say "I don't think so". I think "I think, ***No***" works fine with a special tone of voice in spoken English though.

Comment: "*I think not*" is also fine, but it's a pretty *emphatic* negative.  However you should add more detail to the question to explain which you think is correct, and any research to support that conclusion.

Comment: My point was that, as a non-native English speaker, I hold doubts as to whether the expression 'I think not' could be interpreted in the sense that I am having no thought whatever. For instance, while practising transcendental meditation successfully, one's mind is devoid of any thought, so in a situation such as that, I believe I could properly say 'I think not.'

Comment: Yo pienso que no= I think not. "I think not"  never means you don't think. It means: you don't agree with something. "I think no" should be used with great caution.

Comment: Thank you. So, if I understand well, to express that there is no thinking at all going on, I could not say,

*When I am totally absorbed in deep meditation, I think not.*

Correct?

Comment: @Carlos When no thinking is going on, you might say _I'm not thinking_ or _I don't think_. The continuous form is most likely.

Answer (score 2):

**I think not** is the correct choice of the two you propose.

**I think no** is ungrammatical. You might be able to write **I think--no** where the double hyphens represent an em-dash which itself represents a speaker pausing to think and change what he was going to say.

You might be able to use something like this:

> "Is science any thing other than logic applied to the manifested existences?
>
> "I think no, it is exactly as described."

But that's part of a larger construction.

**No** might be a simpler answer if you disagree.

**I don't think so** might be a little more gentle and could be followed by **...because...** and then you list reasons why you disagree.

**I think not** is tending towards a formulaic phrase and tends to be used as a strong negation, possibly because in current English we don't often use such old fashioned constructions with the negating adverb at the end of the sentence. The most notable exception is possibly when following **did** as in **I did not**. Otherwise you sound like you're trying to imitate English from a few hundred years ago and that pattern sounds odd today.

Comment: "The most notable exception is possibly when following did as in I did not." - any auxiliary verb really (have not, will not)

Comment: @Maciej That would be a different structure. It's what some linguists call *code* or *auxiliary stranding*. In this case, however, *not* is a pro-form substituting for the subordinate clause.